# How to Split Continuous Labelled Data?

Tags: decision-trees, implementation

I've started studying decision trees, and I noticed that the examples online used categorical features to split the data at each node. I'm working on data sets with a binary classification output and a collection of categorical and continuous features. I was wondering: **how would one would decide where to split continuous data for a decision tree node?**

Since a continuous feature would exist on a single-variable interval, my idea was to just consider those points which existed in the "overlap" region between the two labelled groups. I would start with an initial estimate (the midpoint of the overlap region). Then, I would move my boundary line next to another point in the overlap region. I would calculate the error rate from the confusion matrix that this classification would yield. If the error rate is lower than the one from the current boundary estimate, I replace my estimated boundary with the new boundary that was just proposed. I repeat this process for each point in the overlap region until I've found a partition which minimizes the error rate.

Is this a reasonable way to split continuous data? I've seen people talk about Gini impurity, although I do not understand why one would use that instead of error rate. I've implemented my described algorithm in python and it seems to do as good a job as is possible for reasonable data sets.